# With ASP.NET Core 3.1, how can I strip the Home controller from a page URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I remove the "Home" controller path from page URLs in my ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 web application?

Rather than render this URL ...

```
www.mysite.com/Home/About
```

... I want to see this:

```
www.mysite.com/About
```

Presently I'm moving an old MVC .NET web application from Visual Studio 2013 (.NET Framework 4.7.2) to Visual Studio Code using ASP.NET Core 3.1.  My previous application registered this route, which produced the effect shown above.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RemoveHomeFromURL",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyWebsite.Controllers" }
);
```

I'd like to get a similar result in this new ASP.NET Core web application. I've defined these endpoints in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "AreaA",
    areaName: "AreaA",
    pattern: "AreaA/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "AreaZ",
    areaName: "AreaZ",
    pattern: "AreaZ/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

What endpoint pattern do I need to apply in order to strip the "/Home/" path from views targeted by the HomeController?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Actions only for Home controller (domain.com/about instead of domain.com/home/about)
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "HomeActionOnly", 
      pattern: "{action}", 
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you, Bruce!